# create map of Europe with higher degree of granularity for admin regions

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I'm working on a project to render [a map of Europe](http://dashboard.edsa-project.eu/), for the purpose of displaying data related to data science jobs around the EU and the different constituent member nations.

At the moment the map shows the demarcation of countries, but what I would like is for the map to show not only countries but also the component administrative regions, such as the departments of France and the federal states of Germany, equivalent to the 50 states of the US.

In the file [europeMap.js](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/jobanalysis-dashboard/blob/master/public/js/graphs/europeMap.js) we read in the file [europe.json](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/jobanalysis-dashboard/blob/master/public/data/map/europe.json)

```
1  /**
2   * Contains the class for constructing the map of Europe.
3:  * europe.json was created using
4   * data from Natural Earth: http://naturalearthdata.com
5   * and GDAL: http://www.gdal.org/ 
.


244  
245          // load the europe data
246:         d3.json("data/map/europe.json", function (error, europe) {
247               if (error) { throw error; }
```

According to my prior experience with d3 the right way might be to try to create a file similar to europe.json- also using [natural earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/)- but with different administrative regions- is that right?

If I want to show those regions- like this one: http://milkbread.github.io/subpages/webmapping_examples/d3-choropleth_germany.html 
what would I have to do to change that file `europe.json` file?

could it just be swapped with the current one?

Comment: Your file its incomplete. It has not administratives regions on it. Just country's boundary and marks point.-

Comment: that's true- it renders the map that I linked to in the top paragraph at the map view in "a map of Europe", but if I want to show those regions- like this one: http://milkbread.github.io/subpages/webmapping_examples/d3-choropleth_germany.html do you know what I would have to do to change that file?

Comment: Grab this file from Natural Earth: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.zip for states If you wanna go deeper (countries and municipalities) check this: http://www.gadm.org

Comment: gadm.org gives you i.e for France: FRA_adm0.shp, FRA_adm1.shp, FRA_adm2.shp, FRA_adm3.shp, FRA_adm4.shp and FRA_adm5.shp Disadvantage: you need to download every country Advantage: you can select what show

Comment: and then I need to run some command to put them all together into one file- and then I have to parse that file when I display it?

Comment: Yeap. I use QGIS to put all together and then export as .geojson then compact to .topojson